# When should/must I declare/instantiate ReactiveCocoa objects as stored properties versus local variables?

Tags: reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3, racsignal

(Applies to `ReactiveCocoa` 4 or maybe 3)

In most examples and cases I have seen, `ReactiveCocoa` objects like `MutableProperty<TVal, TErr>` or `SignalProducer<TVal, TErr>` that are involved in hooking up the user interface to data are at least instantiated in some `setupBindings` or similar method invoked in the constructor.

I have experienced several cases in which I had non-working code that suddenly "just worked" when I moved the *declaration* of the object from the scope to a stored property or vice-versa. For instance, in pseudo-code:

```
class Wtf {

    // doesn't work

    init() {
        let prop = MutableProperty<Dah, Dah>()...
        doSomethingWith(prop)
    }

    // also doesn't work

    private let prop: MutableProperty<Dah, Dah> = MutableProperty<Dah, Dah>(Dah())

    init() {
        doSomethingWith(prop)
    }    

    // works?

    private let prop: MutableProperty<Dah, Dah>

    init() {
        prop = MutableProperty<Dah, Dah>(Dah())
        doSomethingWith(prop)
    }
}
```

So it seems there are a few basic questions.

Given some `ReactiveCocoa` object...

1. When should I *declare* it as a property (`let` or `var`) vs a local instance variable?
2. When should I *instantiate* it as a stored, computed, or other variant of property versus instance
3. When should it be a function `return`?

Answer (score 0):

`MutableProperty` is a `class`. In other words: it has reference semantics.
Unlike `Signal` (whose lifetime [depends on a termination event](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/23dab6c3e69a64fb4d027e29ff90ac6896a7bac8/ReactiveCocoa/Swift/Signal.swift#L15-L16)), the lifetime of a `property` is defined by the owner. If no object is holding a reference to a property, it will be deallocated.

For that reason, the answer to your question would normally be to store it inside of another class.

A common thing to do is to keep the `MutableProperty` `private`, and only expose a readable one:

```
final class Owner {
    private let mutableProperty = MutableProperty<Type?>(nil)
    public var property: AnyProperty<Type?> {
        return AnyProperty(self.mutableProperty)
    }
}
```